# Android AVD emulator not running app, but device does? (OpenGL)

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

Hi I am trying to run some sample openGl code on an emulator.  I am new to Android development.  It crashes on the emulator but not my device, a Samsung Galaxy Note phone N7000.

The AVD settings I tried were:

```
Target: Android 4.1 - API Level 16
CPU/ABI: ARM (armeabi-v7a)
SD Card: 32 MiB
Skin: Built-in : WGA800
```

Here are the errors on the console:

```
10-15 13:23:34.287: E/Trace(621): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
10-15 13:23:34.848: D/libEGL(621): Emulator without GPU support detected. Fallback to software renderer.
10-15 13:23:34.878: D/libEGL(621): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLES_android.so
10-15 13:23:34.947: D/gralloc_goldfish(621): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
10-15 13:23:34.977: W/dalvikvm(621): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)
10-15 13:23:34.977: E/AndroidRuntime(621): FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 72
10-15 13:23:34.977: E/AndroidRuntime(621): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No configs match configSpec
10-15 13:23:34.977: E/AndroidRuntime(621):  at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$BaseConfigChooser.chooseConfig(GLSurfaceView.java:863)
10-15 13:23:34.977: E/AndroidRuntime(621):  at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$EglHelper.start(GLSurfaceView.java:1024)
10-15 13:23:34.977: E/AndroidRuntime(621):  at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1401)
10-15 13:23:34.977: E/AndroidRuntime(621):  at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1240)
10-15 13:23:35.377: I/Choreographer(621): Skipped 67 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
10-15 13:23:36.658: I/Choreographer(621): Skipped 72 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

Thanks
Bob

Comment: Galaxy Notes don't have Jelly Bean (4.1) do they?

Comment: ^ No official releases yet I think, but there are others 3rd party ROMs out there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
10-15 13:23:34.848: D/libEGL(621): Emulator without GPU support detected. Fallback to software renderer.
```

Just recreate or edit your emulator and be sure that under the hardware list you have

**GPU Emulation** set to **Yes**